# Update position or rotation property of ARNode with ar_flutter_plugin

Tags: flutter, arcore

I have already added 2 nodes to the ARView and I want to update the position or rotation of the node by pressing a button. Idk if I need to use the ARSessionManager or the ARObjectManager and how to do it.

Here is some code I have:

```
        var node = ARNode(
          name: "${modelARList?[i].name}",
          type: NodeType.webGLB,
          uri: "${modelARList?[i].url}",
          scale: Vector3(modelARList![i].xScale, modelARList![i].yScale,
              modelARList![i].zScale),
          position: Vector3(modelARList![i].xPosition,
              modelARList![i].yPosition, modelARList![i].zPosition),
        );
     bool? didAddWebNode = await this.arObjectManager.addNode(node);
```

I want to update my node pressing a button:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
          ARView(
            onARViewCreated: _onARViewCreated,
            planeDetectionConfig: PlaneDetectionConfig.horizontalAndVertical,
          ),
          
          Positioned(
            bottom: 30,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
            child: MainActionButton(
                text: 'Rotate',
                onPressed: _rotate),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```